# How do I see if a user agent is chrome or firefox?

Tags: php

I want to tell if the user agent used to access my page is chrome or firefox. I found a list of [chrome user agents](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/) however the list is **huge** and I don't want to write:

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "agent1" | $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == "agent 2")...
```

and I feel there's *probably* a more efficient way to do so. What should I try?

Comment: Search for `Chrome` in the user_agent string?

Comment: @wumm Isn't that in all of the agents though?

Answer (score 1):

Just search for the string `Chrome`in the user agent

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Chrome")){
   echo "It's Chrome!";
}
```

Comment: Didn't realize it was this easy. Thanks.

Comment: Why downvoted? It doesn't help anybody at all to just downvote, without telling what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$Chrome = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Chrome");
$FireFox = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], "Firefox");


if ($Chrome || $FireFox  ){
 //chrome or firefox
}
```

Comment: First this code can't work, because of the missing ). Second my Safari user agent string is `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.74.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.2 Safari/537.74.9` See the Mozilla?